# Draw a timeline

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given an input of a list of integers representing dates, output an ASCII art
timeline like the following:

```
<----------------------------->
  A     B  C           D    E
```

The above timeline is the output for input `[1990, 1996, 1999, 2011, 2016]`.
Note several things about the timeline:

- The first line of output is a less than sign (`<`), a number of dashes equal
  to `dateOfLastEvent - dateOfFirstEvent + 3` (because one must be added to
  include the last date, and then two more for padding), and then a greater
  than sign (`>`).
- In the second line of output, each event is placed at position `dateOfEvent -
  dateOfFirstEvent + 2` (assuming zero-indexing). Hence, the first event is
  placed at position `2`, two characters to the right of the `<`, and the last
  event is similarly two characters to the left of the `>`.
- Each event is represented by a letter. Event 1 is `A`, event 2 is `B`, etc.
  There will never be more than 26 events. You may use lowercase letters if you
  would like.
- There is no trailing whitespace. The only extra whitespace allowed is a
  trailing newline at the end of the program.

Furthermore,

- The events are not necessarily given in order. Dates are still labelled
  according to their position in the array, though. For example, an input of
  `[2, 3, 1, 5, 4]` must output

  ```
  <------->
    CABED
  ```
- You may be given one or more events as input. For example, an
  input of `[12345]` must output

  ```
  <--->
    A
  ```
- You may assume that the input will never contain duplicate dates.

Input may be given as either an array/list of integers/strings or a single
string separated by any non-numerical character. The allowable range of dates that will be provided as input is `1 ≤ x ≤ 32767`.

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes will win.

Test cases:

```
32767 32715 32716 32750 32730 32729 32722 32766 32740 32762
<------------------------------------------------------->
  BC     G      FE         I         D           J   HA
2015 2014
<---->
  BA
1990 1996 1999 2011 2016
<----------------------------->
  A     B  C           D    E
2 3 1 5 4
<------->
  CABED
12345
<--->
  A
```

Answer (score 5):

### Pyth, <s>37</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
:*dlp++\<*\-+3-eJSQhJ">
"mhh-dhJQG
```

Explanation: (for this the newline will be replaced by `\n` for simplicity)

```
:*dlp++\<*\-+3-eJSQhJ">\n"mhh-dhJQG

                                    - autoassign Q = eval(input())
                                    - G = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    p++\<*\-+3-eJSQhJ">\n"          -    print out the first line

            +3-eJSQhJ               -        Get the number of dashes
                 SQ                 -            sorted(Q)
                J                   -           autoassign J = ^
               e                    -          ^[-1]
              -                     -         ^-V
                   hJ               -          J[0]
            +3                      -        ^+3

         *\-                        -       ^*"-"
      +\<                           -      "<"+^
     +               ">\n"          -     ^+"-->\n"
    p                               -    print(^)

 *dl                                -  work out the number of spaces to print
   l                                -   len(^)
 *d                                 -  ^*" "
:                                 G - For i in V: ^[i] = G[i]
                          mhh-dhJQ  -  Work out the positions of the characters
                          m      Q  -  [V for d in Q]
                               hJ   -     J[0]
                             -d     -    d-^
                           hh       -   ^+2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3A%2adlp%2B%2B%5C%3C%2a%5C-%2B3-eJSQhJ%22%3E%0A%22mhh-dhJQG&input=%5B5%2C+2%2C+4%2C+3%2C+1%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell, <s>120</s> 108 bytes

```
param($a)$n,$m=($a|sort)[0,-1];"<$('-'*($b=$m-$n+3))>";$o=,' '*$b;$i=97;$a|%{$o[$_-$n+2]=[char]$i++};-join$o
```

Takes input `$a` then sets `$n` and `$m` to the minimal and maximal values, respectively. We output the timeline with the next section, by executing a code block `$(...)` inside the string to generate the appropriate number of `-` characters. We then generate an array of the same length containing only spaces, and set our output character to `$i`.

Then, we loop through the input `$a` with `|%{...}`. Each loop we set the appropriate `$o` value. Finally, we `-join` `$o` together to form a string. Since that is left on the pipeline, output is implicit.

Edited to remove the `.TrimEnd()` command, as the last character of `$o` is always guaranteed to be a letter.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\draw-a-timeline.ps1 2015,2014,2000
<------------------>
  c             ba
```

Answer (score 4):

## C - <strike>294</strike> <strike>287</strike> <strike>220</strike> <strike>191</strike> <strike>184</strike> <strike>178</strike> 174 bytes

After staring out with a somewhat insane code I at least have gotten it down a bit ...

***Note:*** *First loop has the requirement that the execution of the binary gives 0 as result from `atoi()` on `argv[0]`. If not, this would result in the binary (name) being included as an event. Examples that invalidates:*

```
$ 42/program 1 2 3
# 42/program gives 42 from argv[0], fail.

$ 1program 3 2 9
# 1program gives 1 from argv[0], fail.

$ 842 3 2 9
# 842 gives 842 from argv[0], fail.
```

*Not sure if this is a valid requirement.*

```
char y[32769];n,m;main(i,a)char**a;{for(;n=atoi(a[--i]);y[n>m?m=n:n]=64+i);for(;!y[++i];);printf("<");for(n=i;i<=m;i+=printf("-"))!y[i]?y[i]=' ':0;printf("-->\n  %s\n",y+n);}
```

Run:

```
./cabed 32767 32715 32716 32750 32730 32729 32722 32766 32740 32762
<------------------------------------------------------->
  BC     G      FE         I         D           J   HA

./cabed 2 1 3 5 4
<------->
  BACED

./cabed 2016
<--->
  A

./cabed 130 155 133 142 139 149 148 121 124 127 136
<------------------------------------->
  H  I  J  A  C  K  E  D     GF     B
```

Ungolfed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char y[32769]; /* Zero filled as it is in global scope. */
int n, m;

int main(i, a) 
    char**a; 
{
    /* Loop argv and set y[argv[i] as int] = Letter, (Event name).
     * Set m = Max value and thus last data element in y. */
    for ( ; n = atoi(a[--i]); y[n > m ? m = n : n] = 64 + i)
        ;

    /* i = 0. Find first element in y that has a value. (Min value.) */
    for (; !y[++i]; )
        ;

    printf("<");

    /* Save min value / y-index where data starts to n.
     * Print dashes until y-index = max 
     * Build rest of event string by filling in spaces where no letters.*/
    for (n = i; i <= m; i += printf("-"))
        !y[i] ? y[i] = ' ' : 0;

    printf("-->\n  %s\n", y + n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 40 <s>41</s> bytes

```
0lY2in:)GtX<-I+(t~32w(ctn45lbX"60hP62hcw
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MGxZMmluOilHdFg8LUkrKHR-MzJ3KGN0bjQ1bGJYIjYwaFA2Mmhjdw&input=WzMyNzY3IDMyNzE1IDMyNzE2IDMyNzUwIDMyNzMwIDMyNzI5IDMyNzIyIDMyNzY2IDMyNzQwIDMyNzYyXQ)

```
0          % array initiallized to 0
lY2        % string 'ABC...Z'
in:)       % input array. Take as many letters as its length
GtX<-I+    % push input again. Duplicate, subtract minimum and add 3
(          % assign selected letter to those positions. Rest entries are 0
t~32w(     % replace 0 by 32 (space)
c          % convert to char
tn45lbX"   % duplicate, get length. Generate array of 45 ('-') repeated that many times
60hP62h    % prepend 60 ('<'), postpend 62 ('>')
c          % convert to char
w          % swap. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 83 characters

```ruby
->a{n,m=a.minmax
s=' '*(d=m-n+3)
l=?@
a.map{|i|s[i-n+2]=l.next!}
puts ?<+?-*d+?>,s}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->a{n,m=a.minmax;s=' '*(d=m-n+3);l=?@;a.map{|i|s[i-n+2]=l.next!};puts ?<+?-*d+?>,s}[[32767,32715,32716,32750,32730,32729,32722,32766,32740,32762]]
<------------------------------------------------------->
  BC     G      FE         I         D           J   HA
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 124

```js
l=>(l.map(v=>r[v-Math.min(...l)]=(++i).toString(36),r=[],i=9),`<-${'-'.repeat(r.length)}->
  `+[...r].map(x=>x||' ').join``)
```

**TEST**

```js
F=
l=>(l.map(v=>r[v-Math.min(...l)]=(++i).toString(36),r=[],i=9),`<-${'-'.repeat(r.length)}->
  `+[...r].map(x=>x||' ').join``)

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

test= [[32767,32715,32716,32750,32730,32729,32722,32766,32740,32762],
[2015,2014],[1990,1996,1999,2011,2016],[2,3,1,5,4],[12345]]

test.forEach(x=>console.log(x+'\n'+F(x)+'\n'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>129</s> <s>126</s> <s>125</s> <s>121</s> <s>117</s> 115 bytes

Uses ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$l=min([$h=max($z=$argv)]+$z)-3;echo~str_pad(Ã,$h-$l,Ò).~ÒÁõ;for(;$l<$h;)echo chr((array_search(++$l,$z)-1^32)+65);
```

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetics only):

```
php -r '$l=min([$h=max($z=$argv)]+$z)-3;echo~str_pad(Ã,$h-$l,Ò).~ÒÁõ;for(;$l<$h;)echo chr((array_search(++$l,$z)-1^32)+65);' 1990 1996 1999 2016 2011 2>/dev/null;echo
```

Ungolfed version:

```
// Get the highest input value.
$h = max($z = $argv);

// Get the lowest value, setting the first argument (script name) to the highest
// so it is ignored.
$l = min([$h] + $z);

// Output the first line.
echo "<".str_repeat("-",$h - $l + 3).">\n  ";

// Iterate from $l to $h.
for(;$l <= $h;)
    // Find the index of the current iteration. If found, convert the numeric
    // index to a char. If not found, print a space.
    echo ($s = array_search($l++, $z)) ? chr($s+64) : " ";
```

- Saved 3 bytes by printing leading spaces from the loop and changing `<=` to `<`.
- Saved a byte by using `str_pad` instead of `str_repeat`.
- Saved 4 bytes by using bitwise logic to convert 0 (`false`) to 32, and everything above 0 to 97 onwards. Then convert that number to char.
- Saved 4 bytes by using negated extended ASCII to yield `<`, `-`, `>` and newline
- Saved 2 bytes by negating string after padding instead of before

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 109 bytes

*includes +1 for `-p`*

```
$l=A;s/\d+/$h{$&}=$l++/ge;($a,$z)=(sort keys%h)[0,-1];$o.=$h{$_}//$"for$a..$z;$_='<'.'-'x($z-$a+3).">$/  $o"
```

Expects input on stdin: space separated numbers. Example:

```
$ echo 2016 2012 2013 | perl -p file.pl
<------->
  BC  A
```

Somewhat readable:

```
$l=A;                                   # Intialize $l with the letter A
s/\d+/$h{$&}=$l++/ge;                   # construct %h hash with number->letter
($a,$z) = (sort keys %h)[0,-1];         # grab min/max numbers
$o .= $h{$_} // $" for $a..$z;          # construct 2nd line: letter or space
$_= '<' . '-' x ($z-$a+3) . ">$/  $o"   # construct 1st line, merge both lines to $_ output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <del>173</del> <del>172</del> 182 bytes

since Python is missing yet, here is my first post:

```
import sys
d=dict([(int(v),chr(65+i))for(i,v)in enumerate(sys.argv[1:])])
k=sorted(d.keys())
f=k[0]
s=k[-1]-f+3
o=list(" "*s)
for i in k:o[i-f+2]=d[i]
print "<"+"-"*s+">\n"+"".join(o)
```

the original looks following:

```
import sys

dates = dict([(int(v), chr(65+i)) for (i,v) in enumerate(sys.argv[1:])])
keys = sorted(dates.keys())
first = keys[0]
out_size = keys[-1] - first + 3
out = list(" " * out_size)
for date in keys: out[date - first + 2] = dates[date]
print "<" + "-" * out_size + ">\n" + "".join(out)
```

Comment: You need `import sys` in your golfed version.

Comment: ok, I will, but I have never seen any imports in the golfed versions, so I just left it out

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, <s>106</s> 99 characters

```groovy
{n=it.min()
o=[l="A"]
it.each{o[it-n]=l++}
"<${"-"*(it.max()-n+3)}>\n  "+o.collect{it?:" "}.join()}
```

Sample run:

```
groovy:000> print(({n=it.min();o=[l="A"];it.each{o[it-n]=l++};"<${"-"*(it.max()-n+3)}>\n  "+o.collect{it?:" "}.join()})([32767,32715,32716,32750,32730,32729,32722,32766,32740,32762]))
<------------------------------------------------------->
  BC     G      FE         I         D           J   HA
```