# Reading a timeline

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Inspired by [Draw a timeline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73477/draw-a-timeline).

Given a timeline of events, output the date for each event.

A timeline will be given in the form

```
    2000
--AF-C-------E--D---B--
```

Where the first line shows a known point in time. The known year is always the character below the first digit of the known year

You may assume:

- On the timeline itself, each character represents one year.
- There will always be at least one event
- The events don't have to be in order
- You may assume every character in the range between `A` and the furthest character is present
- There will be at most 26 events
- The known point will not have any padding to the right
- There can be negative numbers in both the known point and the output
- You will not have to handle numbers bigger than 2^32
- You will not have to handle ranges bigger than 2^8
- You can take input as lowercase letters instead of uppercase

You should write a program that takes a timeline in this form and outputs the key dates in order (A, B, C, D...)

You may output in a convenient form but you must take input in the format given.

Test cases:

```
    2000
--AF-C-------E--D---B--
[1998, 2016, 2001, 2012, 2009, 1999]

     10
--C-AB--D
[9, 10, 7, 13]

     0
--ABCDEFG--
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

          5
--ABCDEFG--
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: ... input in the format given. That is? A single string with a newline? or 2 strings?

Comment: 2 strings or a string with a newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

Takes input as lowercase letters instead of uppercase.

```
VS@GJw+-sz/zdxJN
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

Code:

```
ð¢>UágF²N>.bkX-¹+,
```

Explanation:

```
ð¢                   # Count the number of spaces before the year starts
  >                  # Increment by 1
   U                 # Pop and store this into X
    á                # Keep the alphabetic characters of the second input
     g               # Take the length
      F              # For N in range(0, length), do...
       ²             #   Take the second input
        N>           #   Push N and increment by 1
          .b         #   Converts 1 to A, 2 to B, etc.
            k        #   Find the index of that letter in the second input
             X       #   Push X
              -      #   index - X
               ¹     #   Get the first input, which contains the year
                +    #   Add to the difference of the index
                 ,   #   Pop and output the sum
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w7DCoj5Vw6FnRsKyTj4uYmtYLcK5Kyw&input=ICAgIDIwMDAKLS1BRi1DLS0tLS0tLUUtLUQtLS1CLS0)

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 72

```js
(a,b,r=[])=>[...b].map((x,i)=>r[parseInt(x,36)-10]=+a+i-a.search`\\d`)&&r
```

**Test**

```js
f=(a,b,r=[])=>[...b].map((x,i)=>r[parseInt(x,36)-10]=+a+i-a.search`\\d`)&&r

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[['    2000','--AF-C-------E--D---B--'],
['     10','--C-AB--D'],
['     0','--ABCDEFG--'],
['          5','--ABCDEFG--']]
.forEach(t=>{
  var a=t[0],b=t[1],r=f(a,b)
  console.log(a+'\n'+b+'\n'+r+'\n')
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 68

Line 1 is input as a quoted command-line option and line 2 is input from STDIN:

```bash
s="${1//[0-9]}"
fold -1|nl -v$[$1-${#s}]|sort -k2|sed '/-$/d;s/.$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 58 + 1 = 59 bytes

```
/\d/;$b=<>;for$c(A..Z){($z=index$b,$c)>-1&&say$_+$z-$-[0]}
```

Breakdown:

```
/\d/;                    # Match first digit in input string, this will set $-[0]
$b=<>;                   # Read next line (--A--CB--...) into $b
for $c (A..Z){           # Iterate over A, B, C, ... Z
  ($z=index$b,$c) >-1 && # If the character is found inside $b
  say $_+$z-$-[0]        #   then print
}
```

Requires `-n` and the free `-M5.010`:

```
# Added line breaks for each test case
$ perl -nE'/\d/;$b=<>;for$c(A..Z){($z=index$b,$c)>-1&&say$_+$z-$-[0]}' tl
1998
2016
2001
2012
2009
1999

9
10
7
13

-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3

-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
$ cat tl
    2000
--AF-C-------E--D---B--
     10
--C-AB--D
     0
--ABCDEFG--
          5
--ABCDEFG--
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 22 bytes

```
V+r\AJeSKwJ+xKN-izT/zd
```

No I did not write this before I posted the challenge.

Explanation:

```
                       - autoassign z = input()
 +r\AJeSKwJ            -  create range of letters
        Kw             -      autoassign K = input()
      eS               -     sorted(K)[-1] (get the biggest character)
     J                 -    autoassign J = ^
  r\A                  -   range("A", ^)
 +        J            -  ^ + J
V                      - for N in ^: V
               -izT/zd - Get the number at the start
                izT    -   int(z, 10)
               -       -  ^-V
                   /zd -   z.count(" ")
           +           - V+^
            xKN        -  K.index(N)
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%2Br%5CAJeSKwJ%2BxKN-izT%2Fzd&input=++++2000%0A--AF-C-------E--D---B--&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 118

Man, today is the day of long Python answers.

```
def f(p,l):o=sum(x<'0'for x in p);e={x:i-o+int(p[o:])for i,x in enumerate(l)if'@'<x};return list(map(e.get,sorted(e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>71</s> 67 bytes

```pl
($a=<>)=~/\d/;$b=<>;say$a+$_-$-[0]for grep{$_+1}map{index$b,$_}A..Z
```

Thanks to [@dev-null](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48657/dev-null) for 12 bytes!

```pl
($a=<>)=~/\d/;  # read first line of input, find position of first digit
                # (saved in the $- variable)
$b=<>;          # read the second line
                                           A..Z  # generate range 'A','B',...
                            map{index$b,$_}      # find index for each
                  grep{$_+1}                     # select only those != -1
              for                                # foreach of remaining...
say$a+$_-$-[0]                                   # calculate proper date
```

Answer (score 0):

### Seriously, 40 bytes

```
' ,c,;)l@;±)@-(x@;╗@Z`i3╤τ+@┐`MX╜ú∩S`└`M
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=JyAsYyw7KWxAO8KxKUAtKHhAO-KVl0BaYGkz4pWkz4QrQOKUkGBNWOKVnMO64oipU2DilJRgTQ&input=JyAgICAyMDAwJwonLS1hZi1jLS0tLS0tLWUtLWQtLS1iLS0n)

Explanation to come later after further golfing.